# Jacquet Langlands correspondence

Tags: langlands-conjectures, automorphic-forms, nt.number-theory

I have one issue with the Jacquet Langlands correspondence. The Weyl law for $H$ modulo a congruence subgroup and the Weyl law for cocompact groups are different. So why does this not contradict this functoriality? What am I missing?

I have not yet studied the Jacquet Langlands correspondence explicitly yet. How explicit are the lifts, about the level etc.? I know that there is not an expansion formula for cocompact groups available as we have it for groups with a parabolic element.

**Update:** After a reading a little bit, I found a paper which focuses exactly on the first part of the question and also gives references for the second part of the question:

Risager, Morten S. Asymptotic densities of Maass newforms. J. Number Theory 109 (2004), no. 1, 96–119.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit"? You know the local components (using the Weil representation) and Shimizu gave an explicit global realization of the correspondence using theta series (see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=333081).

Comment: For a quick statement about the level, see Chenevier's IHP notes (The infinite fern and families of quaternionic modular forms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what sense is the Weyl law different for congruence subgroups and cocompact groups?

At any rate, the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence is not a bijection between the two cuspidal spectra. More precisely, let $D$ be a quaternion algebra over a number field $F$, and consider the groups $G=PD^\times$ and $G'=PGL_2$. Then the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence injects the automorphic representations of $G(\mathbb{A}_F)$ into those of $G'(\mathbb{A}_F)$. A cuspidal representation $\pi$ of $G'(\mathbb{A}_F)$ lies in the image of this map if and only if $\pi_v$ is a discrete series representation of $G'(F_v)$ at all places $v$ where $D$ ramifies. So unless $G'=G$, the image will miss several cuspidal representations of $G'(\mathbb{A}_F)$.

I think the lifts are not explicit in the sense that they are not given by an explicit construction.

Comment: There appears an additional $T log T$ term for congruence subgroups.

Comment: The $T\log T$ term is an error term, i.e. it is really $O(T\log T)$. There is an error term for the cocompact case as well, perhaps it is not spelled out so explicitly.

Comment: no, it is a main term, they Weyl law is $C T^2 + D T log T + O( T / log T)$ for congruence subgroups and $C' T^2 + O( T / log T)$ for cocompact groups.

Comment: @pm: Very interesting. Do you know the value of $D$ for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Also, there seems to be a main term $ET$ as well.

Comment: Discrete series at non-archimedean places means here supercuspidal, right? Or are Steinberg representations also allowed?

Comment: @Marc: By discrete series I meant square-integrable. So I think Steinberg representations are also allowed. Admittedly, I am no expert on this topic.